# Monthly report for leave apply

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have two tables one is tblemployee having employee name, employee id and another table tblleaves having empid,Leave_Date, fromDate, toDate, Description.

If employee choose one date leave it stores the date value to Leave_Date and if employee choose multiple dates it store value of from date and to date.

In the output page I want an employee name, Leave Days and Leave Dates. Leave Dates have dates from Leave_date, FromDate and ToDate.

```
     <?php 


        if(isset($_POST['apply'])){

        $ym=$_POST['month'];
        list($Year, $Month) = explode("-", "$ym", 2);

        $sql = "SELECT 
       tblemployees.FirstName,
       tblemployees.LastName,
       count(tblleaves.empid) as Leave_Days,
       GROUP_CONCAT( tblleaves.Leave_Date SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS leave_dates
    FROM
       tblleaves
       JOIN tblemployees
          ON tblleaves.empid = tblemployees.id
    WHERE YEAR(Leave_Date) = $Year
       AND MONTH(Leave_Date) = $Month
    GROUP BY tblemployees.EmpId";

        $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $cnt=1;
        if($query->rowCount() > 0)
        {
        foreach($results as $result)
        {               ?>  
          <tr>
            <td> <?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
              <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->FirstName);?>&nbsp;<?php echo htmlentities($result->LastName);?></td>
               <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Leave_Days);
     ?></td>
<td><?php echo htmlentities($result->leave_dates);

    ?></td><?php $cnt++;}}}?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want output of page is

```
employee name     Leave Days      Leave Dates 
KrishnanR            3              12-06-2019, 13-06-2019, 14-06-2019
                                     (FromDate and ToDate)
PrakashR             1              12-06-2019
                                     (Leave_Date)

SelvaK               3        12-06-2019,13-06-2019&14-06-2019,|  14-06-2019
                                      (FromDate and ToDate) |  (Leave_Date)
```

Comment: You can use conditions in query.
Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select

Comment: I didnt understand that. can you help me with this code.

Comment: Help me to find it

Comment: Surely it would be simpler to store 1-day leave the same way you store multi-day leave !?!?!?

Comment: May i know why You guys put negative mark

Comment: if you know the answer give it if you dnt have then why you guys do like this??

Comment: @Bhargav Rao Did you notice the newer post was marked as a duplicate thus closing for any other answers on that one leaving this the only open one on this topic. Deleting my answer here is not helpful.

Comment: OK I got it thanks for negative mark

Comment: One thing I don't understand. You tagged it with `mysqli`, but you clearly use `PDO` in the code. Which is it?

Comment: That mean you can answer it to mysqli also. Now I added that.

Comment: Anyone have an answer kindly mention here.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code based on your requirement, didn't tested it. Let's give it a try.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['apply'])){

$ym=$_POST['month'];
list($Year, $Month) = explode("-", "$ym", 2);

$sql = "SELECT tblemployees.FirstName, tblemployees.LastName, count(tblleaves.empid) as Leave_Days,
               IF( t2.FromDate IS NOT NULL AND t2.ToDate IS NOT NULL , 
                    CONCAT(t2.FromDate, ',', t2.ToDate, ',' ,t2.Leave_Date), 
                    t2.Leave_Date) as 'Leave_Dates'
          FROM tblleaves JOIN tblemployees ON tblleaves.empid = tblemployees.id
         WHERE YEAR(Leave_Date) = $Year AND MONTH(Leave_Date) = $Month
      GROUP BY tblemployees.EmpId";

$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               
$leavedates = explode(',', $result->Leave_Dates);
$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime($leavedates[0]),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime($leavedates[1])
);
$listofleaves = [];
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
    $listofleaves[] = $value->format('Y-m-d');       
}
$listofleaves[] = $leavedates[2];
    ?>  
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
      <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->FirstName);?>&nbsp;<?php echo htmlentities($result->LastName);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->Leave_Days);
?></td>

<td><?php echo htmlentities(implode(',' , $listofleaves);


?></td><?php $cnt++;}}}?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194658/discussion-on-answer-by-naveen-monthly-report-for-leave-apply).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following crude example...

Sample schema (borrowed and adapted from P.Salmon):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee_leave;
CREATE TABLE employee_leave
(leave_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,employee_id INT NOT NULL
,leave_from DATE NOT NULL
,leave_to DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO employee_leave
(employee_id
,leave_from
,leave_to
) VALUES
(11,'2019-05-30','2019-06-02'),
(11,'2019-06-05','2019-06-05'),
(11,'2019-06-06','2019-06-06'),
(11,'2019-06-30','2019-07-11'),
(12,'2019-05-30','2019-07-11'),
(13,'2019-05-11','2019-05-12');
```

Sample code:

```
<?php

include('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT employee_id
     , leave_from
     , leave_to
     , datediff(leave_to,leave_from)+1 days
  FROM employee_leave
 ORDER
    BY employee_id
     , leave_from; -- ORDER BY is not strictly necessary, as the ordering can be done in presentation code.
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $array[] = $row;
}

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
  if($v['days']>1){
    $days = ' days'; } else { $days = ' day'; }
  $new_array[$v['employee_id']][] = $v['leave_from'].' - '.$v['leave_to'].' ('.$v['days'].$days.')';
}

print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Using the schema above, this code outputs...

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-05-30 - 2019-06-02 (4 days)
            [1] => 2019-06-05 - 2019-06-05 (1 day)
            [2] => 2019-06-06 - 2019-06-06 (1 day)
            [3] => 2019-06-30 - 2019-07-11 (12 days)
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-05-30 - 2019-07-11 (43 days)
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-05-11 - 2019-05-12 (2 days)
        )

)
```

Note that this result considers all days as working days

Comment: I have Leave_Date in database

Comment: Want to print leave dates of employee per month

Comment: I'm confident that you can figure out how to adapt this code to suit.